# Putting two videos next to each other, improving performance

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this command I put together with quite some effort to put two videos next to each other.

> ffmpeg -y -i i1.mov -i i2.mp4 -filter_complex
>
> [0:v]scale=1824:1026,pad=width=1920:height=1080:x=0:y=27:color=black,crop=1641:923:170:79,scale=1920:1080[vl];
>
> [1:v]scale=2016:1134,crop=1759:1080:48:27,pad=width=1920:height=1080:x=161:y=0:color=black,crop=1641:923:170:79,scale=1920:1080[vr];
>
> [vl][vr]hstack=shortest=1 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast output

It works, but it is not elegant.

How to shorten it and make it more performant?

Comment: What are the original resolutions?

Comment: @Gyan 1920 x 1080